# Checkbox that will enable/disable a button

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I have a component that contain a checkbox,I want to affect a button. 
on the beginning the button is disabled, as soon as the checkbox is checked it will be enabled else unchecked = disabled

the html

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>I agree</ion-label>
<ion-checkbox   (ionChange)="changeEvent($event)"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
<button (click)="register()" class="register-btn" [disabled]="checkedbtn" ion-button icon-only >
</button>
```

the ts

```
checkedbtn : boolean = true

  changeEvent(event) {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      this.checkedbtn = false
      console.log(this.cguCheck)
    }
    this.checkedbtn = true;
  }
}
```

At the moment i'm getting an error

> cannot read property 'checked' of undefined

Comment: did you tried to log that change event and check how it looks like? maybe post that log here.

Comment: @marvstar that's throwing me the error i tried to console log checkedbtn, but i got nothing

Comment: did you tried my answer?.Let try this answer and let me know.Its working tested iam maded stackblitz example for you

Comment: @LisaN i ment you should log the whole event you got from the html component. 'changeEvent(event){ console.log(event); }'

Answer (score 3):

why not simply using [(ngModel)]? It has no much sense using a changeEvent

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>I agree</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="checkedbtn"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
<button (click)="register()" class="register-btn" [disabled]="!checkedbtn" 
     ion-button icon-only >Register
</button>
```

Comment: I agree. The rest are over complicating things for a small task. ngModel is your way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an working example for you,

Html File,

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>I agree</ion-label>
      <ion-checkbox   (ionChange)="changeEvent($event)"></ion-checkbox>
   </ion-item>
     <button (click)="register()" class="register-btn" [disabled]="checkedbtn" ion-button 
          icon-only >Register
     </button>
```

Typescript File,

```
changeEvent(event) {
   console.log("event.target.value",event);
   if(event.checked){
      this.checkedbtn = false;
      console.log("checkedbtn value",this.checkedbtn);
   }else{
      this.checkedbtn = true;
   }        
  }
```

I maded stackblitz for you,

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-nkycpg

Let try this once and let me know.

Comment: why not simply using [(ngModel)]? It has no much sense using a changeEvent

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event.value`

```
changeEvent(event) {
    if (event.value) {
      this.checkedbtn = false
    }else{
      this.checkedbtn = true;
    }
}
```